# syntax error fro Parentheses after the command (SELECT FROM Nested)

Tags: sql, vb.net, syntax

Vb.net problem with syntax select from a nested:

---

```
SELECT derivedtbl_2.amel_code, 
       derivedtbl_2.kala_code, 
       derivedtbl_2.kala_name, 
       derivedtbl_2.kala_unit, 
       derivedtbl_2.kala_price, 
       Sum(derivedtbl_2.sum_qty_amani)                                AS 
       sum_qty_amani, 
       Sum(derivedtbl_2.sum_price_amani)                              AS 
       sum_price_amani, 
       Sum(dbo.sales_view.sum_qty_sales)                              AS 
       sum_qty_sales, 
       Sum(derivedtbl_2.sum_qty_amani - dbo.sales_view.sum_qty_sales) AS 
       remaining_qty_amani, 
       ( derivedtbl_2.sum_qty_amani - dbo.sales_view.sum_qty_sales ) * 
       derivedtbl_2.kala_price                                        AS 
       remaining_price_amani 
FROM   (SELECT amel_code, 
               kala_code, 
               kala_name, 
               kala_unit, 
               kala_price, 
               Sum(sum_qty_amani)   AS sum_qty_amani, 
               Sum(sum_price_amani) AS sum_price_amani 
        FROM   (SELECT dbo.amel_kala_amani_tbl.amani_code, 
                       dbo.amel_kala_amani_tbl.amel_code, 
                       dbo.amel_kala_amani_tbl.kala_code, 
                       dbo.kala_price_active_view.kala_name, 
                       dbo.kala_price_active_view.kala_unit, 
                       dbo.kala_price_active_view.kala_price, 
                       Sum(dbo.amel_kala_amani_tbl.qty) 
                               AS sum_qty_amani, 
                       Sum(dbo.amel_kala_amani_tbl.qty * 
                           dbo.kala_price_active_view.kala_price) 
                               AS 
                       sum_price_amani 
                FROM   dbo.amel_kala_amani_tbl 
                       INNER JOIN dbo.kala_price_active_view 
                               ON dbo.amel_kala_amani_tbl.kala_code = 
                                  dbo.kala_price_active_view.kala_code 
                GROUP  BY dbo.amel_kala_amani_tbl.amani_code, 
                          dbo.amel_kala_amani_tbl.amel_code, 
                          dbo.kala_price_active_view.kala_name, 
                          dbo.kala_price_active_view.kala_unit, 
                          dbo.kala_price_active_view.kala_price, 
                          dbo.amel_kala_amani_tbl.kala_code 
                HAVING ( dbo.amel_kala_amani_tbl.amani_code < @Param1 ) 
                       AND ( dbo.amel_kala_amani_tbl.amel_code = @Param2 )) AS 
               derivedtbl_1 
        GROUP  BY amel_code, 
                  kala_code, 
                  kala_name, 
                  kala_unit, 
                  kala_price) AS derivedtbl_2 
       INNER JOIN dbo.sales_view 
               ON derivedtbl_2.amel_code = dbo.sales_view.amel_code 
                  AND derivedtbl_2.kala_code = dbo.sales_view.kala_code 
GROUP  BY derivedtbl_2.amel_code, 
          derivedtbl_2.kala_code, 
          derivedtbl_2.kala_name, 
          derivedtbl_2.kala_unit, 
          derivedtbl_2.kala_price, 
          ( derivedtbl_2.sum_qty_amani - dbo.sales_view.sum_qty_sales ) * 
          derivedtbl_2.kala_price
```

---

please help me.

Comment: Classic! Really, classic.

Comment: What's the error message you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every subquery or nested query should have name.
example:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM T1 WHERE ID>50) D
```